# This is a question where I'm supposed to get a door mat design as shown in the body. I'm not able to get "-" for every line

Tags: python

So I'm actually supposed to get a design as following:

```
------------.|.------------
---------.|..|..|.---------
------.|..|..|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.---
----------WELCOME----------
---.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.---
------.|..|..|..|..|.------
---------.|..|..|.---------
------------.|.------------
```

which it's an `N*M` mat size. where N is an odd number and M is `3*N`.
for which I wrote this:

```
N,M=map(int,input().split())
for i in range(1,N,2):
     pattern=".|."*i
     var=pattern.center((m-len(pattern))/2,"-")
     print(var)
```

and when I execute this I don't get "-" for every line. I want to know where did I go wrong.
I know that there's much more to do apart from this but can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: `m` isn't defined in your code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current output.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var=pattern.center(M,"-")
```

Assuming your `m` is actually `M` (the second input number).

So with input "9 27" produces:

```
------------.|.------------
---------.|..|..|.---------
------.|..|..|..|..|.------
---.|..|..|..|..|..|..|.---
```

which I assume you can then complete.

> The center() method will center align the string, using a specified
> character (space is default) as the fill character.

So the syntax is:

```
string.center(length, character)
```

and the result is a string of length 'length' with the 'character' used to fill before and after the centered string.

So the complete code might be:

```
N,M=map(int,input().split())
for i in range(1,N,2):
     pattern=".|."*i
     var=pattern.center(M,"-")
     print(var)
var="Welcome".center(M,"-");

print(var);
for i in range(N,1,-2):
     pattern=".|."*(i-2)
     var=pattern.center(M,"-")
     print(var)
```

Here are some simple tests which you can enter in a python [sandbox](http://pythonsandbox.com/) or your IDE:

```
print("123".center(20,"="));
print("123".center(3,"="));
print("123".center(4,"="));
print("123".center(5,"="));
print("1234".center(0,"="));
```

Produces:

```
========123=========
123
123=
=123=
1234
```

Experiment!

Note1: Since M must always be `N*3` then why enter it and just compute it.  Since it is entered you then must consider what happens if `M != N*3`.